# How to add custom columns in a multi column table?

Tags: tables, multi-column, column-headers

I am designing a control where the 1st column, 'Investment Categories,' corresponds with lots of purposes shown on the right. The users need to be able to add additional Purpose Columns as they work in the program.

I have a + icon next to the Investment Categories since the users need to be able to add additional Investment categories too.

I am stuck because I dont know how to show the user to add additional Inv Categories ( which adds rows) and additional Purposes (which adds Columns).

Should it be done via an icon, or text.... kinda lost. I appreciate you guys advice in advance.[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's will be consistent to use same control for adding columns as well as rows. The role of consistency here is to support learnability as a usability feature.

Though, it's better to display add button more prominent (affordable). Using tooltips is also good. In addition, add delete buttons for the categories and purposes, too, to support add-delete operations.

To minimize visual noize, delete buttons could be displayed for active (mouse over) elements only.
[image]